# How to include Meta tag through CGI.pm

Tags: perl

I want to include the following HTML meta tag into a cgi script:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex,nofollow,noarchive,noodp,nosnippet" />
```

But why this doesn't print out the result?

```
use CGI;
print
    $query->start_html(-title =>'MyWeb',
       -meta => {
         -name =>'googlebot',
         -content =>'noindex,nofollow,noarchive,noodp,nosnippet'}
    ),p;
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Note that all answers so far `use strict`. You should, too. Always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use strict; 
use warnings;  
use CGI;
my $query = CGI->new();
print
    $query->start_html(-title =>'MyWeb',
       -meta => {'googlebot' => 'noindex,nofollow,noarchive,noodp,nosnippet'}
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Works for me...

In your example, you did not initialize `$query`, could that be the problem?

```
use CGI;
use strict;
print
    CGI->start_html(-title =>'MyWeb',
       -meta => {
         -name =>'googlebot',
         -content =>'noindex,nofollow,noarchive,noodp,nosnippet'}
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on my machine:

```
use CGI qw(start_html);
use strict;
use warnings;


print
    start_html(-title =>'MyWeb',
       -meta => {
         'googlebot' => 'noindex,nofollow,noarchive,noodp,nosnippet',
        }
    );
```